# How to bind input fields from model forms into vue

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-models, django-forms

Usually you can grab input fields you manually created through `v-model` like these:

```
<input class="form-control mb-2" name="username" v-model="username" type="text" placeholder="username" autocomplete="off">
<input class="form-control" type="password" v-model="password" placeholder="password">
```

However, how can I grab and place `v-model` on fields that are auto-generated by Django through model forms?

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ user_form }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Register</button>
</form>
```

Comment: can you set attributes for auto-generating fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any attribute in your `forms.py`

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            # add v-model to each model field
            field.widget.attrs.update({'v-model': name})
```

Comment: I used this instead, but thanks so much for the idea! :) `first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'v-model': 'registration.first_name'}))`